# Configure Custom DataSource While using Liquibase in Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, liquibase

I am using Liquibase in my Spring Boot Application.So far the code works fine when I am using the default datasource.But I don't really want to hardcode these properties in my application.properties file.How can I configure the custom dataSource for LiquiBase by getting properties from config server.

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=password
```

I created a POJO to inject the properties from the config server

DataSourceConfig.class

```
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="db") // in my config server I have created a properties file with prefix db
public class DataSourceConfig {
    
    private String url;
    private String userName;
    private String secret;
    
   //getters and setters
}
```

Now I want to create a Custom DataSource something like,is this the right way to createCustom DataSource when using LiquiBase or if you could suggest me the appropriate way to achieve this.Can we use the DataSourceBuilder class when we are using LiquiBase or we need some extra configuration like defining SpringLiquiBase

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    
    return DataSourceBuilder
        .create()
          .userName(dataSourcConfig.getUser())
          .password(dataSourcConfig.getSecret())
        .build();
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about Spring Cloud Config Server? Then you don't need to do anything because it will use the properties from the config server

Comment: yes I am talking about the Spring Cloud Config Server , but that does not have the default spring.datasource.url rather it is with the prefix db.datasource.url and also if I want to retrieve the password securely and set it explicitly in the DataSource Bean , so I want to know a way how can i create a custom dataSource when using LiquiBase, can we use the DataSourceBuilder class or we need some extra configuration like defining SpringLiquiBase